# Facebook authentication callback on Windows Phone using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, facebook, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I am developing a Windows Phone app with a help of Caliburn.Micro framework. I am trying to implement Facebook login using this [tutorial](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2014/12/windowsphone-store-81-facebook.html).

`ContinuationManager` is causing me problems, since it assumes not using MVVM model and keeping the whole code in code behind of a view. Is there a clean way of returing the control and passing the `WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs` to the `LogInViewModel` (not to `LogInView`) so that authentication process could continue?

In other words, how can I make the 
`public async void ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker( WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)` method get invoked in the `LogInViewModel` after user successfully finishes the Facebook login process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get this working, let me give you mine...

I needed to get OAuth connection with a 3th party and for all communications with that party I created a `Service class` - this class implements the `IWebAuthenticationContinuable` interface.
In other words all API calls are in there AND also the `ContinueWebAuthentication` method.
Inside the ContinueWebAuthentication method I invoke a Status event - this is also declared on the Service class - to notify any listeners about the actual result status of the OAuth handling.

So only thing left to do is register for that event in the ViewModel where you will initiate the start of the OAuth process and act upon the status changed,  for validating if the OAuth process was ok or not.
Starting the actual OAuth process is done by just triggering a method ( in my case on the Service class the method GetAccessToken() ) and in this method you start the `WebuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue()` method.

Other solution would be to use MVVM messaging instead of a real event. But that are just semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Caliburn and I implemented Facebook login recently.

In my LoginViewModel I call `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(url);` to initiate the login.

In App.xaml.cs I override the OnActivated method, I check if the arguments are from the authentication broker and if they I, send them as a message.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{            
    base.OnActivated(args);

    switch (args.Kind)
    {
        case ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation:
                OnWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation((WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs)args);
                break;
        }
}

private void OnWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
{
    var eventAggregator = container.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>()
    eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(args);
}
```

My LoginViewModel implements `IHandle<WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs>` and in the `Handle(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs message)` gets the Facebook token and does the actual login with the service.